# mysql query that counts uniqe field without missing content

Tags: mysql

I have this query:

```
SELECT 
    S.first_name,
    S.last_name,
    S.username,
    S.EntryID, 
    P.EntryID AS id,
    P.name AS period_name,
    COUNT(DISTINCT S.EntryID) AS nume_of_students 
FROM 
    periods P,
    students S,
    periods_students PS 
WHERE 
    P.EntryID=PS.period_id 
AND 
    S.EntryID=PS.student_id 
AND 
    P.EntryID IN ( 206,363,1050,1156,1158,1160,206,363,1050,1156)
```

but it returns only one row in the table of students, however I need it return the students for each `p.EntryID`.

Comment: Presumably, you're missing a GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 0):

The `COUNT` function requires a group. If you use a grouping function but don't actually define a group, it will use the entire result set as the group. The first record will be returned with a COUNT of the size of the result set.